# Angular Modal triggering an ng-hide/ng-show

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm building out a modal that takes 10 lines of input and when clicked to close randomizes them and "should" display out side the modal. Through other research I have found that I must use a service to make everything work right. However this service is not properly changing over my var for changing over true/false for my ng-hide. 
Some code below

Main HTML

```
<body ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
<my-modal-content></my-modal-content>
<button class="btn btn-small"
ng click="open(lg,'ModalInstanceCtrl')">Add</button>

<ul ng-controller="MainCtrl" >
    <button class="btn" ng-click="test()">Test</button>
<li ng-hide="toggle" ng-repeat="random in randomTeams">{{random.team}}</li>
</ul>




 <script src="js/vendor/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="js/vendor/angular-animate.js"></script>
 <script src="js/vendor/angular-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
 <script src="js/Modal.js"></script>
 <script src="js/setTeams.js"></script>
 <script src="js/randomizeTeamservice.js"></script>
</body>
```

My-modal-content

```
    <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Set Team Names</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="input-append" ng-repeat="team in teams | limitTo: 10">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="team.team"  
placeholder="Team {{$index + 1}}" value="{{$index}}">  
</div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok(); 
add(this)">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-
click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

Modal Controller

```
app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal) {
$scope.animationsEnabled = true;

$scope.open = function (size,controller) {

 $uibModal.open({
  animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller:   controller ,
  size: size,
  });
};
});

// Please note that $uibModalInstance represents a modal window (instance)  
dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, randomService) {

$scope.toggle = randomService.showTeams();

$scope.ok = function () {
$uibModalInstance.close({

}

);
$scope.toggle = false;
  console.log($scope.toggle);

};

$scope.cancel = function () {
$uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
});
```

Finally the Service

```
app.factory("randomService", function(){
var teams = [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}];
var randomTeams = teams.slice(0);
var showTeams = true;


 return{
  randomTeams: function(){
      return randomTeams;
  },
  teams: function(){
      return teams;
  },
  showTeams: function(){
      return showTeams;
  }
}

});
```

So why won't the ng-hide work?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Moved some things around but here it is.

Moved the randomize function to the controller and added a getter so a function will retrieve the toggle (true/false) value.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, randomService) {
$scope.teams = randomService.teams();
$scope.randomTeams = randomService.randomTeams();



$scope.toggle = function(){
    return randomService.getTeams();
}

$scope.add = function(team, show) {
for( var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 $scope.teams.splice(i, 1, team.teams[i]);
}
  randomService.shuffle($scope.randomTeams);
    $scope.toggle(); 

};

});
```

In the service factory in addition to adding the shuffle function and a getter function. I added a line of code that will change the showTeams from true to false.

```
app.factory("randomService", function(){
 var teams = [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}];
 var randomTeams = teams.slice(0);
 var showTeams = true;


 return{
  randomTeams: function(){
      return randomTeams;
  },
  teams: function(){
      return teams;
  },

  shuffle: function shuffle(array) {
  showTeams = false;
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

 // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

// Pick a remaining element...
randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
currentIndex -= 1;

// And swap it with the current element.
temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
 }

 return array;
  },
   getTeams: function(){
       return showTeams;

  },

 }


});
```

lastly `ng-hide="toggle:`  changed to `ng-hide="toggle()"`